# BigQuery Create Table Query from Google Sheet with Variable item string field into Repeated Field

Tags: google-bigquery

I hope I explain this adequately.

I have a series of Google Sheets with data from an Airtable database. Several of the fields are stringified arrays with recordIds to another table.

These fields can have between 0 and n - comma separated values.

I run a create/overwrite table SELECT statement to create native BigQuery tables for reporting. This works great.

Now I need to add the recordIds to a Repeated field.

I've manually written to a repeated field using:

```
INSERT INTO `robotic-vista-339622.Insurly_dataset.zzPOLICYTEST` (policyID, locations, carrier)
VALUES ('12334556',[STRUCT('recordId1'),STRUCT('recordId2')], 'name of policy');
```

However, I need to know how I to do this using SELECT statement rather than INSERT. I also need to know how to do this if you do not know the number of recordIds that have been retrieved from Airtable. One record could have none and another record could have 10 or more.

Any given sheet will look like the following, where "locations" contains the recordIds I want to add to a repeated field.

SHEETNAME: POLICIES

```
|policyId   |carrier    | locations                       |
|-----------|-----------|---------------------------------|
|recrTkk    |Workman's  |                                 |
|rec45Yui   |Workman's  |recL45x32,recQz70,recPrjE3x      |
|recQb17y   |ABC Co.    |rec5yUlt,recIrW34                |
```

In the above, the first row/record has no location Id's. And then three and two on the subsequent rows/records.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if answering my own question is the correct way to show that it was solved... but here is what it took.

I create a Native table in BigQuery. the field for locations is a string, mode repeated.

Then I just run an overwrite table SELECT statement.

```
SELECT recordId,Name, Amount, SPLIT(locations) as locations FROM `projectid.datasetid.googlesheetsdatatable`;
```

Tested and I run linked queries on the locations with unnest.